# Strip HTML tags on custom code from the_content

Tags: theme-development, rss, the-content

I"m making a custom RSS feed and need a way to strip HTML tags from a custom code that grabs the first paragraph from a post.

This is what I'm using:

```
<?php
                    $paragraphAfter = 1; // shows image after paragraph 1
                    $paragraphsShow = 1; // shows first two paragraphs
                    $content = apply_filters('the_content', get_the_content());
                    $content = explode("</p>", $content);
                    $max = (count($content) < $paragraphsShow) ? count($content) : $paragraphsShow;
                    for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
                        echo $content[$i] . "</p>";
                    if ($i == ($paragraphAfter-1)) {
                } } ?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php ?

Comment: Please format you code for better readeable, thanks.

Comment: do you only want to get the first para without the tags?

Comment: How do I save PHP code in a string? Tried `<?php $test = '<?php echo test ?>'?>` and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Mark Kaplun advice, I fixed my problem. Just wish there was a way to like a comment.

```
<?php
                    $paragraphAfter = 1; // shows image after paragraph 1
                    $paragraphsShow = 1; // shows first two paragraphs
                    $content = apply_filters('the_content', get_the_content());
                    $content = explode('</p>', $content);
                    $max = (count($content) < $paragraphsShow) ? count($content) : $paragraphsShow;
                    for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
                        echo **strip_tags($content[$i])** . '</p>';
                    if ($i == ($paragraphAfter-1)) {
                } } ?>
```